# Python getting KeyError when working with json

Tags: python, json

I am working with json in my python program

```
temp = json.loads(text2)
data = temp["data"]
try:
    ld = data["all"]
    globals()['currentbrowserall'] = ld
    del data["all"]
except:
    s = str(sys.exc_info()[0])
    s2 = str(sys.exc_info()[1])
    s3 = str(sys.exc_info()[2])
    print "%s, %s, %s" % (s, s2, s3)
```

Problem is i keep getting exceptions.KeyError on "all" while every time the Key is there and the data aswell and everything works like it should but it outputs the error. Why? is there something wrong?

Here is a sample of the json

```
{
  "data": {
  "all": [
  {
    "focused": false,
    "windowId": 469,
    "tabs": [
      {
        "active": false,
        "title": "Update Driver Booster",
        "url_short": "www.iobit.com"
      }
    ]
  }
],
"timeline": [
  {
    "hostname": "www.youtube.com",
    "startStr": "8:31",
    "duration": 317,
    "endStr": "8:36",
    "startDate": {
      "hours": 8,
      "minutes": "31"
    },
    "endDate": {
      "hours": 8,
      "minutes": "36"
    }
  },
  {
    "hostname": "stackoverflow.com",
    "startStr": "8:50",
    "duration": 110,
    "endStr": "8:52",
    "startDate": {
      "hours": 8,
      "minutes": "50"
    },
    "endDate": {
      "hours": 8,
      "minutes": "52"
    }
  }
]
  }
}
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know what you're feeding it?

Comment: just do `temp.keys()` and `data.keys()` after  `data = temp["data"]` statement.

Comment: provide your input json data?

Comment: I'm not getting any error though...
i/p https://pastee.org/55z35
o/p https://pastee.org/mm5v3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure your `data` dict has no attribute called `all`:-

1. Check it by printing the dict before using `del` (`print data`).
2. Use the following to ensure you do not get an exception:-

   if data.has_key('all'):
     del data['all']